# JQuery pop out wont work.

Tags: jquery, css

Hi just wanna ask why my JS wont work here

```
$('#toggle').click( 
   function() {
      $('#popout').animate({ top: -10px }, 'slow', function() {
          $('#toggle').html('Close');
      });
  }, 
  function() {
      $('#popout').animate({ top: 50 }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#toggle').html('Show');
      });
   }
);
```

i am trying to make the menu show: 
http://jsfiddle.net/N4ZHd/2/

Please help.

Comment: `.click()` gets only one function.

Comment: Worth to mention that up until jQuery 1.8 there used to be a [.toggle() event](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) that indeed used two functions, but it's now depracated and removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `click()` only takes one function, and that is what is called when the event (clicking) is triggered. If you are trying to alternate between functions, one way is to use an if statement along with the element's data property:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    if(!$('#popout').data('open')){
        $('#popout').animate({ top: '-10px' }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#toggle').html('Close');
        }).data('open', true);
    } else {
        $('#popout').animate({ top: '50px' }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#toggle').html('Show');
        }).data('open', false);
    }
});
```

Also, if you are going to include units when specifying a new style (i.e. top: '10px') you must place quotes around the value. In your case, however, you could just use `-10` and `50`, as jQuery automatically assumes you are talking about pixels if you haven't specified.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ZHd/3/)

And if you wanted to use ternary operators to shorten your code:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    isOpen = $('#popout').data('open');
    $('#popout').animate({ top: isOpen ? '50px' : '-10px' }, 'slow', function() {
        $('#toggle').html(isOpen ? 'Close' : 'Open');
    }).data('open', isOpen ? false : true);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ZHd/7/)

Comment: How can you apply this on here: jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/4 But this time it must be hover and also while popping out the icons must be in hover state?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you cant use two functions in click.

```
var toggle = false;
$('#toggle').click(function () {
    toggle = !toggle
    $('#popout').animate({
        top: (toggle == true ? "-10px" : "50")
    }, 'slow', function () {
        $('#toggle').html((toggle == true ? "close" : "Show"));
    });
});
```

use a bool variable and use if statements

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/N4ZHd/5/)

Comment: How can you apply this on here: http://jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/4/ But this time it must be hover and also while popping out the icons must be in hover state?